# PHP programming , MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have the following SQL statement to inserts data from a table to another table but the number of the mother table is less than the child table, can anyone correct me, thanks for helping

```
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT Nid FROM admins WHERE Nid='$Nid'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

  if( $row > 0 )
  {
      $sql =  "INSERT INTO sickness_details (pnid, dFullName, dposition, dhospital, date)
SELECT '$pnid', admins.FullName, admins.position, admins.hospital, admins.date 
FROM admins WHERE admins.Nid = '$Nid'";
    if( mysql_query($sql) )
     echo "Inserted Successfully ";
   else
     echo "Insertion Failed";
}
 else
 {
     echo "National Id $Nid  not exist";

 }
```

Comment: We need your table structure!

Comment: my admins table contains 
id, Nid, FullName, position, hospital.

my sickness_details contains
id, pind, dFullName, dposition, dhospital, date, sicktype, treatment

Comment: we need more information. As is there is no way to debug. What are the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
  INSERT INTO sickness_details (pnid, dFullName, dposition, dhospital, date)
  SELECT '$pnid', admins.FullName, admins.position, admins.hospital, NOW() 
  FROM admins WHERE admins.Nid = '$Nid';
```

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: can you give me output of your $sql variable

Comment: in the admins table i don't have the date, i want to insert the current date

Comment: the result is insertion faild. 
the full code is 

 $res = mysql_query("SELECT Nid FROM admins WHERE Nid='$Nid'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

   if( $row > 0 )
   {
       $sql =  "INSERT INTO sickness_details (pnid, dFullName, dposition, dhospital, date)
  SELECT '$pnid', admins.FullName, admins.position, admins.hospital, admins.date 
  FROM admins WHERE admins.Nid = '$Nid'";
     if( mysql_query($sql) )
      echo "Inserted Successfully ";
    else
      echo "Insertion Failed";
 }
  else
  {
      echo "National Id $Nid  not exist";
   
  }

Comment: if your field is of `DATE` type use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()`

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't mention the columns you have no data for.

```
INSERT INTO ('no_data','stuff') VALUES ('','foobar');
```

becomes

```
INSERT INTO ('stuff') VALUES ('foobar');
```

### Syntax in mysql

It's a good rule of thumb to actually log the error when debugging (mysql_error)

A good code highliter could help aswell. You are using a column named `date`. this is however a reserved word used by mysql. change it to `date`. Or even better change it to a name that tells me more about it. What kind of date? start? end? birthday? ...

Comment: but the table that i add data into has more fields than the table that i get data drom

Comment: ... so what is the exact problem then?

Comment: insertion failed, 


 $res = mysql_query("SELECT Nid FROM admins WHERE Nid='$Nid'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

   if( $row > 0 )
   {
       $sql =  "INSERT INTO sickness_details (pnid, dFullName, dposition, dhospital, date)
  SELECT '$pnid', admins.FullName, admins.position, admins.hospital, admins.date 
  FROM admins WHERE admins.Nid = '$Nid'";
     if( mysql_query($sql) )
      echo "Inserted Successfully ";
    else
      echo "Insertion Failed";
 }
  else
  {
      echo "National Id $Nid  not exist";
   
  }